# How to Display attachments image from access db in picturebox

Tags: c#, oledb

im trying to display image from database Attachments in picturebox but im getting error on

```cs
ImageByte = (byte[]) vcom.ExecuteScalar();
```

it say

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

here is my code

```
byte[] ImageByte = null;
MemoryStream MemStream = null;

OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
cn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:/ALL/Database7.accdb";
cn.Open();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = cn;
string sql = "select Attachments from Contacts where ID = 1";
OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);

ImageByte = (byte[]) vcom.ExecuteScalar();

MemStream = new MemoryStream(ImageByte);
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MemStream);
cn.Close();
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the Table definition of `Contacts`? What is the `Column Type` of Attachments column?

Comment: the table name Contacts and inside it a first name last name country region ....... and attachments in column 18 and it have picture i added from database

Comment: But what is the type of "Attachments" column ?

Comment: I mean what is the `Data Type` of the column named attachments? Is it `Long Text`, `OLE Object`, `Hyperlink`, `Attachment`, or other?

Comment: oh it attachment

Comment: no mine is not a file it only a link to picture

Comment: can i show picture of database here how to upload here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `MSAccess`, attachments binary data are located in a sub element of the Attachment field.

This will return a `byte[]`. This byte[] is padded by `MSAccess`, first 20 bytes are contains `MetaData`.

You can use Linq `.Skip()` to get rid of those first 20 bytes

```cs
string sql = "select Attachments.FileData from Contacts where ID = 1";
OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);

byte[] ImageByte = (byte[]) vcom.ExecuteScalar(); //contains 20 extra bytes

MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream(ImageByte.Skip(20).ToArray()); //Read bytes starting at position 20

Image image = Image.FromStream(MemStream); //Will work now
pictureBox1.Image = image;
...
```

Does this work?

Comment: yes it pass execute error but a error on                                                   `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MemStream);`                                                                      the error is                                                                                                                                       _Parameter is not valid._

Comment: The `byte[]` that you are receiving contains MetaData added by MSAccess, you need to extract a part of the byte[] not all, I'm adjusting the answer

Comment: omg it worked for first time thanks a lot dear Jhonathan you really helped  me  , is there a rate or something i can do i searched but didn't find